# bean dependency diagram in eclipse for a java config based spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-ide

I'm using STS/GGTS 3.0.0 in eclipse, my spring project is a mix of java based, and xml based spring configuration.

I'd like to see some dependency diagrams of the spring beans, I can't figure out how to do that.

any ideas?

Kind Regards